# count unique Values in column B based on criteria in column A

Tags: vba, excel

I want to count unique values in column B based on criteria in column A, that is the problem:

- in column A we have the months number:

  ```
  A : 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 *
  ```
- in column B we have the serial number of the cars:

  ```
  B : H185 H185 S556 S556 s521 s521 f221 s521 d558 r5569 d558 d558 r555 r555 *
  ```

I want to know how many cars were produced in each month, and get a response:

```
msgbox ( month 1 , 'NB produced car" , month 2," NB produced cars , ......) .
```

Answer (score 0):

Query-wise you have to do the following:

```
select count(B), A
 from tablename
group by A;
```

This gets you the list... then use it in your application.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach uses `Dictionary` objects to keep a tally of months and unique cars produced. You may have to amend the code to correct for ranges and messages. Let us know if this works for you / if you need more help.

```
Sub CountUniqueByMonth()
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim oDictOuter As Object
    Dim rIterator As Range

    Set rData = Range("A2:A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)

    Set oDictOuter = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each rIterator In rData
        AddToDictIfNotExists oDictOuter, rIterator.Value, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        AddToDictIfNotExists oDictOuter(rIterator.Value), rIterator.Offset(, 1).Value, ""
    Next rIterator


    For Each Key In oDictOuter.Keys
        MsgBox "Month: " & Key & " - " & oDictOuter(Key).Count & " produced car(s)"
    Next Key
End Sub

Private Sub AddToDictIfNotExists(oDict As Object, vKey As Variant, vValue As Variant)
    If Not oDict.exists(vKey) Then
        oDict.Add vKey, vValue
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim msg As String

    With Worksheets("Month-Cars").Range("A1:A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) 'process only given sheet (change the name as per your needs) column "A" cells with numbers
        .Offset(, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(RC1:R" & .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row & "C1,RC1,RC2:R" & .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row & "C2, RC2)" 'use "helper" cells in column "C" to localize unique pairs "month-serial number"
        With .Offset(, 3) 'use "helper" cells in column "D" to associate each month its unique pairs sum
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(" & .Offset(, -3).Address(, , xlR1C1) & ",RC1," & .Offset(, -1).Address(, , xlR1C1) & ",1)" 'calculate unique pairs sum
            .Value2 = .Value2 'get rid of formulas
        End With
        .Copy Destination:=.Offset(, 4) 'use "helper" cells in column "E" to duplicate "month" values and subsequent removing duplicates purposes
        .Offset(, 3).Resize(, 2).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2), Header:=xlNo ' remove months duplicate values

        For Each cell In .Offset(, 4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) 'loop through unique months to build the report message
            msg = msg & "month " & cell.Value2 & ": " & cell.Offset(, -1) & " produced car" & IIf(cell.Offset(, -1) > 1, "s", "") & vbCrLf
        Next cell

        .Offset(, 2).Resize(, 3).ClearContents 'clear all "helper" cells in columns "C", "D" ed "E"
    End With

    MsgBox msg 'prompt the report message

End Sub
```

it's commented so that you can follow the code and make possible changes